# Tool for reverse-engineering M7702 binary?

Tags: disassembly, ghidra, binary

I'm considering reverse-engineering a 1994-era embedded system which CPU is a Mitsubishi M37702S1AFP with external 128k × 8 EPROM that I know how to read.

The CPU has 16-bit registers A, B (data), X, Y (indexes), Stack, Direct Page Register, Processor Status; a 24-bit PC; and an 8-bit Data bank register DT.

[image: M37702]

I have located the instruction set [here](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/mah/77027703-group-users-manual#page=501). Is this compatible with a better known CPU?

Is there any (free) tool that could help? Like an extension for Ghidra, which [reportedly](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#what-processors-are-currently-supported) does not support this instruction set out of the box?

---

Update: I'm now wondering how far the CPU can be from the [65(C)816](https://wiki.superfamicom.org/65816-reference) of SNES fame.